# Function being called when it should not be

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I am learning p5js. I only want the red square to be drawn when it's function is called  `showRect()` however, I only want this function to be called if a condition is met in an `if` statement.

In this case I want the `showRect()` function to be called if variable `show` is equal to 1. (`show = 1`) however the `showRect()` function is being called even when the `show` variable is equal to 0. (`show = 0`)

I cannot work out where I am going wrong with this and have tried booleans and other variable types.

```js
function draw() { 

    var show = 0;

    var showRect = function() {
        fill(255,0,0);
        rect(200,200, 100,100);
    }

    if (show = 1) {
        showRect();
    } 
}
```

Comment: This is an assignment: `show = 1` it returns true. This is a test for equality `show === 1`

Comment: It should be `if (show === 1)`. Careful with the number of equal signs. You are assigning instead of testing for equality.

Comment: You should use == or ===  in ```show == 1```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single `=` sign is assignment.

To check for equality, use `==` or `===`.

```
if (show == 1) {
```

You can read more info here:

- [JavaScript Comparison and Logical Operators](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp)
- [Comparison operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators)

Also, you probably don't want to define your `showRect()` function inside your `draw()` function like that. Instead, put it at the same level as `draw()`:

```
function draw() { 
  // ...
}

function showRect() {
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you made a typo in the `if statement`, use `==` or `===` and `show` is a local variable from that you can't enter if statement in any case:

```
function draw() { 

    --> var show = 0; 

    var showRect = function() {
        fill(255,0,0);
        rect(200,200, 100,100);
    }



   --> if (show = 1) {
        showRect();
    } 
}
```